# I need a query those ID which comes after Pass Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0jd3.png)

Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn0aO.png)

I was trying but it is not working for me

Can anybody assist

Comment: the function you are after is LEAD

Comment: Please show us what you tried. And I suggest not using language such as "a need" because thats more of a demand that a request for help.

Comment: Please do not use images, use formatted text like you started with - why did you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
drop table if exists #have;

CREATE TABLE #have 
(
  ID      [INT]
, Status  [VarChar](8)
);

insert into #have
values
  (1 , 'P')
, (2 , 'F')
, (3 , 'F')
, (4 , 'P')
, (5 , 'P')
, (10, 'F')
, (22, 'F')
;

with cte as
(
select *
     , lag(Status) over (order by ID) as prev
from #have
)

select ID, Status 
from cte
where Status = 'F' and prev = 'P'
;
```